# Como atualizar online um aplicativo feito em Windows Forms?

Tags: visual-studio, instalador

criei um aplicativo em windows forms e, como ainda estou desenvolvendo e ajustando o mesmo, preciso estar atualizando periodicamente.

meu programa está sendo usado em umas cinco máquinas diferentes e sempre que um dos usuários pedem uma atualização eu faço o seguinte:

-desinstalo a versão anterior (estou usando Visual Studio Installer para instalar)
-acesso o banco de dados e altero tudo
-instalo a nova versão

quero saber se tem como meu programa saber se tem uma nova atualização e atualizar sozinho, ou pelo menos fazer as alterações do banco e instalar por cima da versão antiga.

Comment: Você roda a aplicação e banco de dados na mesma máquina? Qual banco*?

Comment: os dois na mesma máquina sim. mysql

Comment: Pra início, sugiro implementar um servidor de banco de dados, assim terá os dados de forma centralizada.